# Rawtherapee: maximum of 100 EXIF lines?

Tags: rawtherapee

Recently I noticed that [rawtherapee](http://rawtherapee.com/) does not save all the EXIF tags present in an image. My Pentax camera saves the lens model under an "Lens ID" tag.

All images which have been processed by rawtherapee seem to have exactly 100 EXIF fields (as checked using the [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/)). Is that by design, or a bug? Can I change it? I would really like to keep the Lens ID tag. Selecting what to save in the Meta TAB does not seem to influence the tags that are saved.

Comment: Have you check whats happen when you load XMP with more than 100 tags?

Comment: Using RT 5.8 and the Jpg from a Canon CR2 with 355 EXIF tags has 332 tags, while the difference can be ascribed to the format change. The RT author(s) can be found [here](https://discuss.pixls.us/c/software/rawtherapee/14).

Comment: @RomeoNinov: what is XMP? And yes, my raw files have more than 100 tags.